# how can i extract the text from chat messages in Skype

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, skype

I am trying to create a bot that makes simple word memes. Most of the work is done but what I am stuck at is that I cannot find a way to use Skype instant messaging as input and output stream. What I want to accomplish is a users instant messages the bot with a word, and the bot replies with the word meme associated with it. This is similar to shibabot on #osuosc IRC server hosted on freenode.

```
 
For example:

User1: .meme night
bot:    such night
           so dark
     wow
```

Is there a way that I can use skype instant messaging as input and output streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a good way to do this anymore.  In this Skype support post, they specifically call out that you can not access chat messages via the Skype API past December 2013.

> "due to technology improvements we are making to the Skype experience, some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work."

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12349/skype-says-my-application-will-stop-working-with-skype-in-december-2013-why-is-that

Comment: Thank you! Are there any third party APIs that I can use for this or even a screen reader?